# How to get mongodb nested documents in Python Pandas dataframe table format

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

|  | name | age | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Steve" | 27 | {"number": 4, "street": "Main Road", "city": "Oxford"} |
| 2 | "Adam" | 32 | {"number": 78, "street": "High St", "city": "Cambridge"} |

However the subdocuments will just appear as JSON inside the subdocument cell

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(list(db.collection_name.find({}))
print(df)
```

how can I get a below 2nd table like this using python?

what is the approach after this?

|  | name | age | address.number | address.street | address.city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steve | 27 | 4 | "Main Road" | "Oxford" |
| 2 | Adam | 32 | 78 | "High St" | "Cambridge" |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to expand the JSON/dict in column `address` into a dataframe of the JSON/dict contents.  Then, join with the original dataframe using [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), as follows:

Optional step: If your JSON/dict are actually strings, convert them to proper JSON/dict first.  Otherwise, skip this step.

```
import ast
df['address'] = df['address'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

Main codes:

```
import pandas as pd

df[['name', 'age']].join(pd.DataFrame(df['address'].tolist(), index=df.index).add_prefix('address.'))
```

**Result:**

```
    name  age  address.number address.street address.city
1  Steve   27               4      Main Road       Oxford
2   Adam   32              78        High St    Cambridge
```

Alternatively, if you have only a few columns to add from the JSON/dict, you can also add them one by one, using the string accessor `str[]`, as follows

```py
df['address.number'] = df['address'].str['number']
df['address.street'] = df['address'].str['street']
df['address.city'] = df['address'].str['city']
```

**Setup**

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': {1: 'Steve', 2: 'Adam'},
        'age': {1: 27, 2: 32},
        'address': {1: {"number": 4, "street": "Main Road", "city": "Oxford"},
                    2: {"number": 78, "street": "High St", "city": "Cambridge"}}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: df['address.number'] = df['address'].str['number']
df['address.street'] = df['address'].str['street']
df['address.city'] = df['address'].str['city']

this part help a lot

Comment: @usmansharifshaik  Right, that's a good option if you want only a limited number of fields.  If you have a big JSON/dict and want all entries in it, the upper part would be more convenient to use.

Comment: @usmansharifshaik  Besides accepting my answer, you can also upvote it , if you find it helpful to you, by clicking the up arrow ▲ (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on use case, it may make more sense to setup an [aggregation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.aggregate) pipeline and [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the necessary nested documents up to the top level:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(db.collection_name.aggregate([{
    '$project': {
        '_id': 0,
        'name': '$name',
        'age': '$age',
        # Raise Sub-documents to top-level under new name
        'address_number': '$address.number',
        'address_street': '$address.street',
        'address_city': '$address.city'
    }
}]))
```

`df`:

```
    name  age  address_number address_street address_city
0  Steve   27               4      Main Road       Oxford
1   Adam   32              78        High St    Cambridge
```

Or if there are many too many fields to do manually we could also [`replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and [`mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#mongodb-expression-exp.-mergeObjects):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': {'$mergeObjects': ["$$ROOT", "$address"]}}},
    {'$project': {'_id': 0, 'address': 0}}
]))
```

`df`:

```
    name  age  number     street       city
0  Steve   27       4  Main Road     Oxford
1   Adam   32      78    High St  Cambridge
```

---

`collection_name` setup:

```py
# Drop Collection if exists
db.collection_name.drop()
# Insert Sample Documents
db.collection_name.insert_many([{
    'name': 'Steve', 'age': 27,
    'address': {"number": 4, "street": "Main Road", "city": "Oxford"}
}, {
    'name': 'Adam', 'age': 32,
    'address': {"number": 78, "street": "High St", "city": "Cambridge"}
}])
```